# WPF Button dynamically added : events not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, user-controls

I've done a WPF base usercontrol for all my usercontrols to inherit of.
In this base usercontrol class, I want to have a button associated to a click event. I've made it like this :

```
public class MBaseUserControl : UserControl
{
  //[...]
    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

        StackPanel mainPanel = new StackPanel();
        EditButton = new Button();
        EditButton.Height = EditButton.Width = 24;
        EditButton.MouseEnter += EditButton_MouseEnter;
        EditButton.MouseLeave += EditButton_MouseLeave;
        EditButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(EditButton_Click);
        EditButton.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        EditButton.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        EditButton.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        EditButton.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;

        StackPanel buttonPanel = new StackPanel();
        Image editButtonImage =     ImageTools.ConvertDrawingImageToWPFImage(Properties.Resources.edit, 24, 24);
        buttonPanel.Children.Add(editButtonImage);

        EditButton.Content = buttonPanel;

        mainPanel.Children.Add(EditButton);
        //Add this to new control
        ((IAddChild)newContent).AddChild(mainPanel);
        SetCMSMode(false);
    }
}
```

But when I click the button on GUI, nothing is firing (neither Mouse events or click event).
What did I miss ?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: I would rather change the base UserControl to have the "static" controls like your edit button on a default style, that way you could bind them to commands defined in the base and not have to worry about hooking event handlers when the content changes. You could add a ContentControl to your default style and bind that to a DependencyProperty on the base.

Comment: My WPF skills seems not be big enough to understand what you would do. Do you have an example of this  ?

Comment: Maybe you should start by looking at the MVVM pattern. Plenty of resources on the internet for that, just google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to template `UserControl` to have its `Content` shown inside some other content. Note, it's untested, but I think it should work.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:DemoUni">
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SomeKey" TargetType="UserControl">
        <Grid x:Name="PART_Grid">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Content" Content="{Binding}"/>
            <!-- ... some other content -->
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In constructor of `UserControl`

```
var dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
// xaml containing control template
dictionary.Source = new Uri("/ProjectName;component/MyUserControlTemplate.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
Template = dictionary["SomeKey"] as ControlTemplate;
```

To access *other content* (`Grid` as example)

```
    private Grid _partGrid;
    private Grid PartGrid
    {
        get
        {
            if (_partGrid == null)
                _partGrid = (Grid)Template.FindName("PART_Grid", this);
            return _partGrid;
        }
    }
```

The little drawback is what you can not access *PART*s in constructor, so that you have to use `Loaded` of `UserControl` to wire up events (subscribe to `Loaded` in constructor, subscribe to button events in `Loaded`).

Comment: If I proceed like that, I will have to subscribe to Loaded in every UserControl I create and redefine my button behavior in every UserControl, which I don't want to do. My first goal is to define only one time in a base class the editButton behavior

Comment: Above code is exactly for base class. Maybe you misunderstood my *subscribe to `Loaded`*, that's because you [can't override](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6568375/1997232) (there is no  virtual `OnLoaded`).

Comment: Hum, I understand what you meant. But now I implemented your code, the grid getter don't work, returns null. I don't understand why (I've not really played with template since now...)

Comment: You can not use *PART*s in constructor. You can assign template in constructor, but it is *applied* (visuals are generated?) some time later. That's why I mentioned `Loaded`, during or after this event you can access *PART*s.

Comment: Thanks, I put the template in loaded too, when I moved it in constructor, it works (not returning null). But my usercontrol are not displayed anymore ? I presume it's linked to ContentPresenter ?

Comment: Try `Content="{Binding Content}"` for `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: Not changing anything

Comment: Try `Content="{TemplateBinding Content}`.

Comment: Thanks, work ! You can also avoid Content attribute, it works too ! And events too

Answer (score 0):

perhaps adding new MouseEventHandler to your code:

```
EditButton.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(EditButton_MouseEnter);
EditButton.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(EditButton_MouseLeave);
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything, I already tried with click event (see code)